# join multiple table using hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

Currently i am facing issue with hibernate to join two tables.

I am looking for hibernate criteria approach to join two different tables. we

have two different entities , which doesn't have any associations. Now i need

to join those two entities using hibernate criteria.

Find the below query to implement criteria

`select * from student s, book b on s.studentId=b.studentId`

Please help me to implement this feature.

Thanks,
Narsi p

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
...
JPAQuery select = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
select.from(student, book);
select.where(student.studentId.eq(book.studentId));
select.list(book)
```

Comment: we are not using JPA library. we are working with Hibernate

Comment: This is Querydsl, for anyone wondering, a framework easier to use than JPA Criteria, and also compatible with JPA and Spring.